# How to create empty 3D array (string) and how to update the value for a specific index?

Tags: python, arrays, string

Im trying to create a 3D-array (8,15,8). I manage to create the array but how to asign values to at specific index?

Got these messages:

File "G:\Min enhet\Python\Travscript.py", line 41, in 
start_list_array[int(1),int(1),int(1)]=attribute.strip()

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

My code:

```
start_list_array = []
for i in range(8): 
    start_list_array.append([])
    for j in range(15):
        start_list_array[i].append([])
        for k in range(8):
            start_list_array[i][j].append([])
               
line_count = 0
race_count = 0
horse_count = 0
attribute_count = 0
for line in input:
    line_count += 1
    if line.strip() in spelformer:
        race_count =+ 1 
     
    elif line_count == 5:
        horse_count += 1

        for attribute in line.split('\t'):
            attribute_count =+ 1
            print(line_count)
            print(race_count)
            print(attribute_count)
            #start_list_array[int(race_count-1), int(horse_count-1), int(attribute_count-1)] = attribute.strip()
            start_list_array[int(1),int(1),int(1)]=attribute.strip()
            print("check2")
            print(start_list_array[int(race_count-1), int(horse_count-1), int(attribute_count-1)])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla lists in Python need to be accessed this way:

```py
start_list_array[1][1][1]
```

The [`__get_item__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) in Python is implemented separately for each class and while other objects such as `numpy` arrays or `pandas` DataFrames may have implementations that support tuples, the `list` object does not.

In fact, your top-level list is agnostic to what it has inside it, for all it knows it could be strings or lists of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

A multidimensional list can be declared with a nested list comprehension.

```
arr = [[[0 for i in range(8)] for j in range(15)] for k in range(8)]
```

and can reference / assign the values with arr[0][0][0]

```
    arr = [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ...
    arr[0] = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    arr[0][1] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    arr[0][0][1] = 0
```